# Insert numpy column in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I need a data frame, which contains just one column which is filled with ones. Here is my code so far.

```
label_values = np.empty(10)
    label_values.fill(1)
    label_df = pd.DataFrame()
    label_df.insert(column=0, value=label_values.transpose(), allow_duplicates=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
    label_df.insert(column=0, value=label_values.transpose(), allow_duplicates=True)
TypeError: insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'loc'
```

As far as I see the problem is that the position (row) for the insert is missing. Do I really need to iterate over the array and insert each single value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
label_values = np.empty(10)
label_values.fill(1)
label_df = pd.DataFrame()
label_df[0] = label_values
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly shorter than the current proposal

```py
pd.DataFrame(np.ones(10))
```

Or

```py
pd.DataFrame(10*[1])
```